# Hide Joomla Template in Controller

Tags: templates, joomla, components

i have a big Joomla 1.5 Problem. I'll create my own Gallery Component/PlugIn and want to add an AJAX Sorting possibility.

In the Backend i want to reorder the Images by Drag&Drop in an Gallery. It works, but for the Output i have the following Problem:

I send the AJAX Request to 
index.php?option=com_cwgallery&controller=gallerie&task=ajax

As i told you, it works, but i want to display the result in a Layer. But Joomla always sends the complete Template and the Result back.

**How can i disable sending the Admin Template??? Hope you understand what i mean?**

Thanks,
Sascha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `&format=raw` to the end of your URL.